# What's the shortcut key for Search the web and Windows in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

In the new Windows 10 in the task bar there is an input box that says, "Search the web and Windows".  I want to put my keyboard input into that box without having to click it everytime.  How can I do this?

Comment: Is it really a "shortcut" key if the search bar is right there?

Answer (score 5):

WinKey + S

*But for me it doesn't search the internet...*

Answer (score 3):

Press the Windows key.  The Start menu will pop up (ignore) and start typing the input will go to the "search the web and Windows" input box.

Comment: That used to work for me in Win8, but it doesn't in Win10, I have to open the separate search thing instead. Is this normal or has it brought over some bad setting in the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 both **WindowsKey** on it's own and **WindowsKey-S** enable direct searching without having to use the mouse.

**WindowsKey** - Brings up the start menu with focus on the search box

**WindowsKey-S** - Brings up Cortana with focus on the search box

For a comprehensive list of shortcuts visit the Microsoft guide:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/keyboard-shortcuts

Note: If you have setup Cortana you get the 'Ask me anything' prompt in the search box rather than the 'Search the web and Windows' option.

Also: If you are a cross platform Mac OS X kind of user then this works similar to AppleKey-Spacebar which brings up Spotlight.